# Spring Framework 4.3.1 mail not resolved

Tags: spring

I updated Spring Framework to 4.3.1, now I am getting an error:

> The import cannot be resolved

for the following imports:

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
```

I have the following libraries for springframework 4.3.1;

```
spring-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar,
aop, aspects, beans, context, context-support,expression, instrument, 
instrument-tomcat, jdbc, jms, messaging, orm, tx, websocket
```

I am not using Maven. Others: Java 8, Liferay 4.3.1, Hibernate 5.2. How can I fix it?

Comment: The *real* fix would be to **use** Maven.

Comment: This is not a Spring problem. The required library is unavailable on the compile-time class-path.

Answer (score 2):

The mail library is found in `spring-context-support` so download `spring-context-support-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar` and add that in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Without maven you may know that you must place the jar in classpath. Follow the jar.
[Java Mail Jar](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)

Check those steps on link above and you'll get it.

[Spring Mail Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html)

If work, tell us a feedback.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If it was Maven you could add the following to your dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```